# error through creating database in plesk by plesklib

Tags: database, subdomain, plesk

I create subdomain in plesk by Install project from Nuget That is in the following link: https://github.com/c1982/plesklib

```
var client = new PleskClient("IP", "UserName", "Password");
var resultSubdomain = client.CreateSubdomain("subdomain.com","SubDomainName");
```

but when trying to create database in to the interface for a subdomain that was already present in the interface by this command:

```
var result=  client.CreateDatabase("subdomain.com", "databaseName" ,"databaseType for example:mssql");
```

the following erro occurs:
Request is invalid. Error in line 5: Element 'webspace-id': '0' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'id_type'.

what is wrong?
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What is the *full* exception, including its call stack? This has nothing to do with SQL Server or C#, it's an error returned by Plesk or the library itself. Given the error `'webspace-id': '0' is not a valid` I'd suspect you havent created a webspace

Comment: Looking at the [method's source code](https://github.com/c1982/plesklib/blob/f066729a1433243c93fda68a1f38e8443b4881aa/src/plesklib/PleskClient.cs#L552), I don't see any code *setting* the `add.webspaceid` property. Nor do I see any tests for database creation. The scarcity of downloads suggests others have encountered similar issues in the past and simply abandoned the library

Comment: yes It's an error returned by the library itself. 
and when I create webSpace by This Library
var resultWebSpace= client.CreateWebSpace("subdomain.com","Ip");
Given the error
"Permission denied."   
Is it possible that I have choosed the false Library?

Comment: It's not an official library if that's what you mean. It has *very* few downloads - just 141 in an entire year. It hasn't been updated in that year either. It would seem it's been abandoned

Comment: Why not call the API directly? Plesk itself provides [low level API examples](https://github.com/plesk/api-examples/tree/master/c-sharp). After all, it's just an HTTP API that accepts XML. You could simplify things a lot too, if you generated the request classes from the [XSD files](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/api-rpc/reference/xml-schemas-for-xml-api-operators.58138/) using xsd.exe or svcutil.exe. Instead of HttpWebRequest you could use HttpClient and the [PostAsXmlAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasxmlasync(v=vs.118).aspx) method

Comment: Thanks for your advice..